# The number of three digit numbers $abc$, which satisfy $a≤b>c$ is

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My approach in this question is as follows,

⇒When $a=1$
$-> 1-1-(0)  / 1-2-(0,1) / 1-3-(0,1,2) ... / 1-9-(0,1...,8)$ ⇒Total numbers = $1+2+3+...+9$
⇒When $a=2$
$-> 2-2-(0,1) / 2-3-(0,1,2) ... / 2-9-(0,1...,8)$ ⇒Total numbers = $2+3+...+9$
⇒When $a=3$
$-> 3-3-(0,1,2) ... / 3-9-(0,1...,8)$ ⇒Total numbers = $3+...+9$

So on counting, we get total numbers as,
$$(1+2+...9)+(2+3+...9)+...(8+9)+(9)$$
$$⇒1^2+2^2+3^2+...9^2$$
$$⇒\frac{(9)(9+1)(2*9+1)}{6}$$
$$⇒285$$

But the actual solution says the answer is,

$$\bigl(2*({9 \choose 1}+{9 \choose 2}+{9 \choose 3})\bigr)$$
$$⇒258$$

I think I have recounted cases, can anyone explain which cases have I recounted??

Comment: That notation is confusing.  Do you mean $a≤b$ AND $b>c$ or something else?

Comment: yes............

Comment: So, for $b=n$ we can choose $a\in \{1,\cdots, n\}$ and $c\in \{0, \cdots, n-1\}$ yes?  Which would make the answer $\sum_{n=1}^9 n^2=285$, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Actually for $a=n$ we can choose $b=n, n+1, ...$ and $c=0,1, ...n-1$

Comment: I am doing it by fixing $b$, not $a$.  Why, in your system, do you get $c<a$?

Comment: If you get the answer as $258$ then explain to me your complete method

Comment: I showed you my method completely and I said it yields $285$.  But perhaps the original source had a different question in mind?  As I say, the notation $a≤b>c$ is, I'd say, unnatural and perhaps it does not mean what I guessed it meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111679/discussion-between-um-desai-and-lulu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given condition should be extended to
$$1\leq a\leq b>c\geq0\ .$$
Given $b\in\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$ we therefore have $b$ choices for $a$ and $b$ choices for $c$. The number of admissible three digit numbers $abc$ therefore is
$$\sum_{b=1}^9b^2={n\cdot(n+1)(2n+1)\over6}\biggr|_{n=9}={9\cdot10\cdot 19\over 6}=285\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

⇒When $a=1$
$-> 1-1-(0)  / 1-2-(0,1) / 1-3-(0,1,2) ... / 1-9-(0,1...,8)$ ⇒Total numbers = $1+2+3+...+9$
⇒When $a=2$
$-> 2-2-(0,1) / 2-3-(0,1,2) ... / 2-9-(0,1...,8)$ ⇒Total numbers = $2+3+...+9$
⇒When $a=3$
$-> 3-3-(0,1,2) ... / 3-9-(0,1...,8)$ ⇒Total numbers = $3+...+9$

So on counting, we get total numbers as,
$$(1+2+...9)+(2+3+...9)+...(8+9)+(9)$$
$$⇒1^2+2^2+3^2+...9^2$$
$$⇒\frac{(9)(9+1)(2*9+1)}{6}$$
$$⇒285$$